# Getting MySQL connection error when java application executed by windows Scheduler

Tags: java, mysql, windows, batch-file

I have created a java tool which reads data from database analyses this data do some operations and  populates table using this data. Created batch file to execute this tool. When I run this batch file manually it works correctly but when I run this batch file using Windows scheduler it gives me following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 4,842 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 974,387 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1900)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3401)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2266)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2687)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2713)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2663)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:888)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:730)
    at com.yagna.report.data.generation.executor.SolutionPartEntityLoader.call(SolutionPartEntityLoader.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 255 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3017)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2125)
    ... 16 more
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: run this query, show variables like "%timeout%"; if wait_timeout is less than 28800, then configure the wait_timeout to 28800

Comment: wait_timeout is 28800 only